# Commas not found in file with php

Tags: php, json, string

I have the following file:

```
[1501801200000,"0.07873100",...], ,[1501804800000,"0.07896500",...]
```

I want to replace the string ', ,' with ','. I've tried it with the following command but it doesn't work. It can find other strings and replace them correctly but not this one. I don't know whether commas are special characters or I'm doing something wrong.

```
$b4 = ', ,';
$r4 = ',';
$str=str_replace($b4, $r4, $str);
```

Many thanks,

Comment: I want to replace the string ', ,' with ',' , i cant see any ,,

Comment: That ain't JSON. Please define _"it doesn't work"_

Comment: @sumit it's between the two arrays... `[1,2,3], ,[4,5,6]`

Comment: i have to say that it works with small files but not with my file that contains thousands of rows. @Phil thanks for the edit, it's not a json file but it's a extract from a larger file that is supposed to be a json and that's why i want to replace that string.

Comment: Either the original source is also not JSON or your extraction process is messing up the format. At the very least, it should be `[[1,2,...],null,[3,4,...]]`

Comment: @Phil you are right is not a json, i want it to be a json and the original file is like that [[1,2,...], ,[3,4,...]]

Comment: So why isn't yours like that? Why have you replaced the `null` with an invalid empty space?

Comment: I extract the data from an API that returns that problem only with a few rows (18 lines with the string ', ,' from a file of thousands of rows. Not sure why to be honest.

Comment: Please answer my question... **Why have you replaced the `null` with an invalid empty space?**

Comment: @Phil Sorry maybe it's a stupid answer but the original file doesn't come with nulls but with empty spaces

Comment: Then why did you say _"the original file is like that `[[1,2,...],null,[3,4,...]]`"_? _Edit:_ I see you've edited it now

Comment: So you're saying this API produces invalid JSON, is that correct? If so, I'd be raising a bug with the maintainers

Comment: *but it's a extract from a larger file that is supposed to be a json* show us the Json instead and tell us what part(s) you need and don't need and we can give you a much more stable solution than str_replace on a string that may look different next week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your format is not json, You can do something like below.
Check the comment

```
$str='[1501801200000,,"0.07873100","0.07925600","0.07827700","0.07896500","460.84900000",1501804799999,"36.32928908",598,"220.92800000","17.41827596","26410.13557257"], ,[1501804800000,"0.07896500","0.07921800","0.07859000","0.07904500","791.20700000",1501808399999,"62.42483876",588,"303.41800000","23.93436841","26415.92962855"]';
//tidy up whitespace
$str = preg_replace('!\s+!', '', $str);
//replace mulitple comma with single one 
$str=preg_replace('!,+!', ',', $str);
echo $str;
```

edit to fix the bug if json strings have spaces

```
$str=preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', ',', $str);
echo $str=preg_replace('!,+!', ',', $str);
```

Comment: If `str_replace()` didn't work on the simple string `", ,"`, I doubt `preg_replace()` is going to do any better. OP hints that it works for small files but not large ones so it's probably a resource limit issue

Comment: @phil Thats why , I tidy up all whitespaces first, please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What if some JSON strings have spaces, eg `["Hello, World"]`